# Why does GHCi report "A constraint must be a monotype" on this instance declaration?

Tags: haskell, types

I've written the following code

```
data I f m = forall x. f x => I (m x)

deriving instance (Show x => Show (m x)) => Show (I Show m)
```

with the following extensions:

```
-XConstrainedClassMethods
-XConstraintKinds
-XDataKinds
-XNoDatatypeContexts
-XExistentialQuantification
-XExplicitForAll
-XExplicitNamespaces
-XFlexibleInstances
-XGADTSyntax
-XGADTs
-XKindSignatures
-XMonoLocalBinds
-XMultiParamTypeClasses
-XNondecreasingIndentation
-XPolyKinds
-XPolymorphicComponents
-XRank2Types
-XRankNTypes
-XStandaloneDeriving
-XTypeInType
-XTypeFamilies
-XTypeOperators
-XTypeSynonymInstances
-XUndecidableInstances
```

However, GHCi complains with this error message:

```
<interactive>:192:19: error:
    • Illegal qualified type: Show x => Show (m x)
      A constraint must be a monotype
    • In the context: (Show x => Show (m x))
      While checking an instance declaration
      In the stand-alone deriving instance for
        ‘(Show x => Show (m x)) => Show (I Show m)’
```

I find that this should be possible, as it seems to be equivalent to the following:

```
data I f = forall x. f x => I x

deriving instance Show (I Show)

instance Show x => Show (m x) ...
```

So therefore

```
instance Show [I Show]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that, for that to work, the type `x` in the context should be universally quantified, as in

```
data I f m = forall x. f x => I (m x)

deriving instance (forall x. Show x => Show (m x)) => Show (I Show m)
```

So, on the left of `=>` we need a `forall x . ...`. This was not allowed by GHC, until recently with GHC 8.6.1 and the [`QuantifiedConstraints` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-QuantifiedConstraints).

Comment: I still have grave reservations about instance resolution for constraint implications. Lots of things that the syntax suggests should work end up not working because GHC reduces the constraint the "wrong" way (for that particular situation).